# PHP deprecated warnings on Drupal pages despite turning them off in php.ini

Tags: drupal-6, php, error-logging

I have PHP deprecated errors flooding log files and Drupal status pages like this:

```
: Function ereg() is deprecated in mysite/includes/file.inc on line 893.
```

I should be able to turn off E_DEPRECATED errors in my php.ini, but it is having no effect despite being set to:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
```

phpInfo() reports error_reporting master value and local value both 22527.

I did a

```
grep -R error_reporting
```

in my document root in the hopes of finding any hard coded error levels and no luck:

```
./includes/common.inc:  // If the @ error suppression operator was used, error_reporting will have
./includes/common.inc:  if (error_reporting() == 0) {
./modules/system/system.module:    'page arguments' => array('system_error_reporting_settings'),
./modules/system/system.admin.inc:function system_error_reporting_settings() {
./modules/system/system.install:      $err = error_reporting(0);
./modules/system/system.install:      error_reporting($err);
```

Nothing that I can see that is supect except possibly the first line in system.install but if I'm right that should turn all errors OFF.

I'm not setting error_reporting in .htaccess, but doing that does not have any effect either.

I'm hoping that there is a solution that doesn't involve hard coding error levels in common.inc (which DOES work, I've tried - but obviously undesirable).

I know the deprecated errors are a result of upgrading to PHP 5.3, but downgrading PHP is not option (new sites are going live now on the same server that have been tested on 5.3, and the sites where these errors occur have 2 months to live). I also cannot upgrade to Drupal versions that play nicely with 5.3 as unfortunately the previous owner haxxed the core modules without documenting his changes.

Version stuff:

PHP 5.3.2-1, Ubuntu 10.04, Drupal 6.13 on one site, 6.5 (!!1!) on the other, Apache 2.2

Comment: From `system_error_reporting_settings` call, it seems like there is a setting for this. What about trying to modify it first?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try editing index.php to be

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);

require_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
```

Answer (score 2):

I have used this on my `php.ini` file and could hide those deprecated errors. Hope it helps you!  =)

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & -E_WARNING
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about disabling error reporting but you can replace all `ereg` functions by `preg_match`..!

Comment: Hoping to do the minimum possible changes to code, bearing in mind that there will be deprecated calls in a bunch of places, including core code.

Comment: Let Microsoft engineers hide errors =p or wait for Drupal 7..!